# Disabling a check box when the UI is opened

Tags: checkbox, click, qt-designer

Is it possible to disable a check box from the moment a UI is run?

I have two steps in my UI. I would like the check boxes of step 2 to remained unchecked until a box in step one is selected.

Is this possible? I can't figure out how to do it with signal/slot.

In the image below I would like Step 2 to be disabled until a box in step 2 is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable checkboxes by default in Qt Designer, set the **enabled** property accordingly (it's at the top of the QWidget section).

For managing the state of the checkboxes, I would suggest adding each set of checkboxes to a [QButtonGroup](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html) (this would probably be done in the `__init__` for your main-window class):

```
    self.group1 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
    self.group1.setExclusive(False)
    self.group1.addButton(self.checkboxA)
    self.group1.addButton(self.checkboxB)
    self.group1.addButton(self.checkboxC)
    self.group1.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleStepOneButtons)

    # self.group2 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
    # ...
    # self.group2.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleStepTwoButtons)
```

And then the handler for the Step 1 checkboxes can control the state of the Step 2 checkboxes like this:

```
def handleStepOneButtons(self, button):
    checked = (self.group1.checkedButton() is not None)
    for checkbox in self.group2.buttons():
        checkbox.setEnabled(checked)
```

Comment: thanks, great answer. Is there also a way to hide a text box? i.e. I have a `?` button which when clicked should display a text with information. Unclicking enabled simply greys the box out, where as I would like to hide it completely. I can always put this in another question if needs be

Comment: @user2761786. Please post a new question.